# Build Search Box into Command Bar

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm wanting to build a search box into my command bar to achieve an effect similar to how the Outlook Mail app on Windows phone handles search.

[image: Without Search]

[image: With Search]

What's the best way of building something like this - are there any built in functions to help?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: On tap show search bar.  Terrible design though, since there's no sign that tapping there will magically enable you to search.

Comment: The search button is in the bar at the bottom of the screen, i've just not shown that in the screenshots.

Comment: Can you put things like a search box into the command bar?

Comment: It will be better to add a control overlapping the `CommandBar` and show/hide it as intended IMHO.

Comment: That might be what I end up doing. Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Or you need a sample code?

Comment: Sample code would be good :)